# Angular optional params cause "%3F" to be added to url if there is a trailing "/"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, optional-parameters

I am running into a weird error with my Angular router.  All of my routes have an optional parameter and when the user adds a trailing / to the URL I get a "%3F"(ASCI code for ?) added into the url at the end of the optional parameter.  One of the routes that behaves this way is written as:

```
when('/:classification?/package/compare', {
   name: 'public-package-compare',
   templateUrl: '/pages/marketing/packages/compare',
   controller: 'PackageCompareController'
})
```

when I visit "/us/package/compare" or "/package/compare" then I am brought to the correct url

If I visit "/us/package/compare/" I am brought to "/us%3F/package/compare" which is not a valid route(this breaks the app).

I know a few ways to hack it to work but I am wondering if there is an established Angular way to deal with this.  I know I can double my routes and add the ones with the / on the end or add a routeInterceptor but I am wondering what the best way to solve this issue is.  I am using Angular version v1.3.0-rc.2 currently and I am using the standard router.  Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Why are you using `rc` version?  There are couple of issue of it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5746) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/9827)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9819) and [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/891acf4c201823fd2c925ee321c70d06737d5944) seemed to have fixed this issue.

Unfortunately the fix was only merged for versions 1.3.10 and up. You will probably have to upgrade your Angular version to resolve the issue.

If you can't upgrade your Angular version, you might try updating your current version with the regex fix, although that sounds like a bad idea.